# C++ system() function for further arguments in ubuntu

Tags: c++, lynx

I didn't really know how to even look for the solution for this one. My problem is, how to execute system commands in c++ using function system(); but for more arguments(Come on it sounds awful). Let me explain: Try for example to type something like this in termianl:

```
lynx www.somewebsiteidunnowhatever.com -get_data
```

And here we go, empty line asking us for input. You can type something like:

```
name=travis&age=45&hobby=football
---
```

After that we would see some result. Now I can't manage how to achievie such behaviour with system(); My c++ script stop responding when that empty line occures. Please help...

Comment: I'm not sure that `lynx` works well with a FIFO on standard input instead of a TTY device. I understand that this is an example, but `wget` and `curl` generally do better jobs at downloading stuff from the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use the format such as following format.

```
system("echo \"name=travis&age=45&hobby=football\" | lynx www.somewebsiteidunnowhatever.com -get_data");
```

using pipe(`|`), you can give a any command's output to any commands as it's input.